# How do I use ActiveModel format validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, activemodel

I'm trying to prevent the saving of a record if it has spaces in the `name` attribute. I'm using Mongoid which includes ActiveModel so it should work exactly the same as ActiveRecord.

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

  validates :name, presence: true, format: { :with => /\S/ }
end
```

Here are my specs. The last 1 fails and I can't figure out why.

```
describe Post do
  describe "validations" do
    # passes
    it "should require a name" do
      post = Post.new name: nil
      post.should_not be_valid
    end

    # passes
    it "should accept valid names" do
      post = Post.new name: "hello-with-no-spaces"
      post.should be_valid
    end

    # fails ?????
    it "should reject invalid names" do
      post = Post.new name: "hello with spaces"
      post.should_not be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want only characters in your name field. So you should use:

```
validates :name, presence: true, format: { :with => /^\S+$/ }
```

See results [here](http://rubular.com/r/WKEBonQMRF). Furthermore you could use `invalid` to make your test more fluent, like in the following:

```
post.should be_invalid
```

By the way, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Yep that worked. I could go either way on the `be_valid` vs `invalid` thing. Nice to know anyway. Thanks.